# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied based on file size

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to transfer an image file to the server

Small files`(6KB, 20KB..)` can be transferred successfully,

But when I try large files (at least `1MB`?) I get permission denied issues in the process of opening the file.

Code to transfer files to server:

```
clientSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
clientSock.connect(('host', 5091))

print('checked')
# ------------------------------------------------
class Handler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        print (f'event type : {event.event_type}\n'

              f'event src_path : {event.src_path}')
        file_path = event.src_path
        if event.is_directory:
            print ("Create directory")
        else: # not event.is_directory
        
            Fname, Extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(event.src_path))
            clientSock.send(b'ready')
            print ("send to get ready")
            def send_img(Fname, Extension):
                capture_file_name = Fname+Extension

                file = open(capture_file_name, "rb")
                time.sleep(5)
                img_size = os.path.getsize(capture_file_name)
                print("img size : ")
                clientSock.send(b'%d' % img_size)
                print(img_size)
                time.sleep(3)
                img = file.read(img_size)
                file.close()
                clientSock.sendall(img)
        
            filename_list = [1]
            file_count = len(filename_list)
            for i in filename_list:
                send_img(Fname, Extension)
```

Error when trying to file name 4.png size 2.41MB:

```
Exception in thread Thread-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site- 
packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 203, in run
    self.dispatch_events(self.event_queue, self.timeout)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\watchdog\observers\api.py", line 376, in dispatch_events
handler.dispatch(event)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\watchdog\events.py", line 331, in dispatch
{
  File "<ipython-input-1-7e86cca481fd>", line 66, in on_created
  File "<ipython-input-1-7e86cca481fd>", line 52, in send_img
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '4.png'
```

What is the cause?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]

Comment: I've added the code

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by giving a delay before opening the file, just like I gave the delay to send the image file size to the server

like this:

```
def send_img(Fname, Extension):
            capture_file_name = Fname+Extension
            time.sleep(2)
            file = open(capture_file_name, "rb")
            time.sleep(5)
            img_size = os.path.getsize(capture_file_name)
            print("img size : ")
            clientSock.send(b'%d' % img_size)
```